# Getting OpenLiteSpeed to execute Perl CGI scripts

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, perl

I just did a clean install of OpenLiteSpeed on Ubuntu 20.04 from the OpenLiteSpeed official repository.

I followed the instructions indicated here to enable the use of Perl scripts: https://openlitespeed.org/kb/guide-to-openlitespeeds-cgi-setup/

It loads .html files without an issue.

When I try to load .cgi script files in the browser, it keeps on downloading the .cgi script files instead of executing them.

I've been looking around for information on this all over the web but I cannot find anything else that helps me solve the issue.

Note that I have only configured paths after the OpenLiteSpeed installation. There is also Apache 2.4 on the machine but it has been stopped to make room for OpenLiteSpeed. With the Apache installation the .cgi scripts execute fine, so it won't be a permission issue, script issue, or Perl installation issue.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here today, you might have better luck on https://askubuntu.com/ .

Comment: What's the path to your script? also, please post a snippet of your cgi script.